# Taking an optional argument naked

Tags: expansion

I want to make a command that grabs a single argument **if any**, succeeds handling it, or fails otherwise. So something like :

```
\NewDocumentCommand\grab{m}{
    \IfValueTF{#1}{
        \handlesuccess{#1}}{
        \handlefailure} 
}
```

Which is fine when there is an argument:`\grab abcd` will expand into `\handlesuccess{a}bcd`.

But it obviously won't compile in the absence of argument ('m' meaning *mandatory argument*). For instance, I would like `ab{grab}cd` to expand into `ab\handlefailure cd`

`xparse` doesn't seem to provide a "naked optional" type of argument. There is 'g' but it only accepts braced arguments.
How then can I achieve this ?

I have very little clue. My only idea in implementing that behaviour would be to try and detect the absence of further input, maybe with something like `\@ifnextchar\EOF` but found no such special symbol so far as `\EOF`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\graborfail{}{
    \@ifnextchar\EOF{ % does not work, be it {}, \relax, or anything I tried
        \handlefailure}{
        \grab}
}
```

Comment: did you mean to write `ab{\grab}cd` with a `\ `?   you would have to use `\@ifnextchar` or `\furturelet` and look for a closing `}` (`\egroup` not `\EOF` which is not a defined command)

Comment: why do you want this, it seems a strange thing to need, You could make _your_ command catch this syntax error but every other command will give a low level error if the input syntax is this wrong `{\fbox}`  or `{\section}` etc all fail without trying to catch this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ```ab{...}cd``` is just here for a context. The point is that in ```{\grab}```, ```\grab``` has nothing ahead.
The motivation is to implement a 'dot' parser that catches any single character.

Comment: yes but `}`  is essentially the only possible fail  so you just need to test for that (and then you can't easily accept `\grab \egroup xyz`  so you catch one thing and lose another.

Comment: if you mean you want to parse the syntax of dot files, make `{` and `}` catcode 12 then the whole issue goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`}` (or another token of catcode 2) is essentially the only thing that won't be taken as `#1` so you can define your command as

```
\@ifnextchar\egroup{\failcommand}{\grab}
```

where `\grab` is your command taking an argument. This necessarily makes the construct not expandable.

Comment: this will make a literal `\egroup`  fail when it would otherwise succeed but distinguishing `}` from `\egroup` is possibly too tricky to contemplate doing just for an error check for a possibly never occurring edge case.

Comment: That would not work in environments, as in ```\begin{someenv} \grab \end{someenv}```

Comment: @kmft3kte yes it would, there is no issue there, `\grab` would get `\end` as `#1` (and may decide to stop and return `\end` or not but actually parsing the token is not an issue.

Comment: I see. I actually assumed that nested structures were hidden to the expansion of inner macros. That feels strange...

Comment: @kmft3kte as I said a literal } character of catcode 2 is the _only_ thing that will give a parse error for a standard non delimited `#1 argument.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation